# Fatal Exception: c.a.c.u java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 83

Tags: android, json, gson

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 52 path $.f
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1197)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:226)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:218)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
       at com.lcbo.companion.common.utils.Utils.getRecentSearches(Utils.java:223)
       at com.lcbo.companion.modules.search.views.ProductsTabFragment.fetchRecentSearches(ProductsTabFragment.java:128)
       at com.lcbo.companion.modules.search.views.ProductsTabFragment.onViewCreated(ProductsTabFragment.java:80)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1676)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3083)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1857)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1745)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7768)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

 }
```

In my app I have search functionality, when ever user searches for something I make a network call fetch suggestions. When user clicks on any of the suggestion I am storing that POJO into shared preferences using Gson and when the screen loads fist I am fetching the stored data from the preferences and deserializing using Gson. It all worked fine but recently I have added ProductTier object to the search item, it never crashed during testing. But it started crashing after the release. I understood that the gson is  throwing error while deserializing but I can't think of any scenario where I am passing an int instead if boolean. Can you guys help me figure out the issue ?

```
 public class SearchItem implements Parcelable {

    private static final int ITEM_KEY_WORD = 0;
    private static final int ITEM_PRODUCT = 1;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("itemKeyword")
    private String itemKeyWord;

    @SerializedName("productId")
    private String productId;

    @SerializedName("productTier")
    private ProductTier productTier;

    private int itemType;
    private boolean isHeader = false;
    private boolean isPopular = false;

    public SearchItem(String name, String productId){
        this.name = name;
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public SearchItem(String name, String itemKeyWord, String productId, int itemType,
                      boolean isHeader, boolean isPopular) {
        this.name = name;
        this.itemKeyWord = itemKeyWord;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
        this.isPopular = isPopular;
    }

    private SearchItem(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.itemKeyWord = in.readString();
        this.productId = in.readString();
        itemType = TextUtils.isEmpty(itemKeyWord) ? ITEM_PRODUCT : ITEM_KEY_WORD;
        productTier = in.readParcelable(ProductTier.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<SearchItem> CREATOR = new Creator<SearchItem>() {
        @Override
        public SearchItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SearchItem(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SearchItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SearchItem[size];
        }
    };

    public String getItemKeyWord() {
        return itemKeyWord;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public int getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(int itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public boolean isHeader() {
        return isHeader;
    }

    public void setHeader(boolean header) {
        isHeader = header;
    }

    public boolean isPopular() {
        return isPopular;
    }

    public void setPopular(boolean popular) {
        isPopular = popular;
    }

    public ProductTier getProductTier() {
        return productTier;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(itemKeyWord);
        dest.writeString(productId);
        dest.writeParcelable(productTier, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        SearchItem that = (SearchItem) obj;
        if (that == null) return false;
        return this.name.equals(that.name);
    }
}

//

public class ProductTier implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("categoryId")
    private String categoryId;

    @SerializedName("liquorTypeId")
    private String liquorTypeId;

    @SerializedName("subCategoryId")
    private String subCategoryId;

    protected ProductTier(Parcel in) {
        categoryId = in.readString();
        liquorTypeId = in.readString();
        subCategoryId = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(categoryId);
        dest.writeString(liquorTypeId);
        dest.writeString(subCategoryId);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<ProductTier> CREATOR = new Creator<ProductTier>() {
        @Override
        public ProductTier createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ProductTier(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ProductTier[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ProductTier[size];
        }
    };

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public String getLiquorTypeId() {
        return liquorTypeId;
    }

    public String getSubCategoryId() {
        return subCategoryId;
    }
}

    class Utils {
    
      public static ArrayList<SearchItem> getRecentSearches(Context context) {
            ArrayList<SearchItem> searchItems = new ArrayList<>();
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String list = preferences.getString(Constants.RECENT_SEARCHES, "");
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    Gson gsonVal = new Gson();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
                        searchItems.add(gsonVal.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), SearchItem.class));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return searchItems;
        }
    
     public static void storeSearchItemToRecentSearches(Context context, SearchItem searchItem) {
            if (searchItem == null) return;
            searchItem.setPopular(false);
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            String list = preferences.getString(Constants.RECENT_SEARCHES, "");
            ArrayList<SearchItem> previousResults = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    Gson gsonVal = new Gson();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
                        previousResults.add(gsonVal.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), SearchItem.class));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
      if (previousResults.size() == 5) {
                previousResults.remove(previousResults.size() - 1);
                previousResults.add(0, searchItem);
            }else {
                previousResults.add(0, searchItem);
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String val = gson.toJson(previousResults);
            editor.putString(Constants.RECENT_SEARCHES, val);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```

the crash is at this line   searchItems.add(gsonVal.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), SearchItem.class)); in the getRecentSearches method.

//Sample response

```
[
    {
        "name": "Blanc",
        "itemKeyword": "Blanc"
    },
    {
        "name": "Blanca",
        "itemKeyword": "Blanca"
    },
    {
        "name": "Blanck",
        "itemKeyword": "Blanck"
    },
    {
        "name": "Louis Jadot Blanchot Chablis Grand Cru 2015",
        "productId": "508416"
    },
    {
        "name": "Parlez Vous Sauvignon Blanc, IGP Loire",
        "productId": "647099"
    },
    {
        "name": "Teperberg Impressions Sauvignon Blanc/Chardonnay KPM",
        "productId": "354704"
    },
    {
        "name": "Spirits > Tequila > Blanco",
        "productTier": {
            "subCategoryId": "15018046",
            "categoryId": "15018",
            "liquorTypeId": "15"
        }
    }
]
```

productTier object may or may not be present it varies with the search term

Comment: Can you please share a sample response ?

Comment: @Swayangjit Thanks for looking at my question. I have added the sample response to the question.

Comment: are you getting the same error for every response ? I mean Line number 83 is constant in all errors or only in this case ?

Comment: @PiyushKumar From my crashlytics report sometimes its at line number 52 also.. but the crash line number of the file Utils which has getRecentSearches method is always same

Comment: this is only happening when new version of prod app is installed on top of previous

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue. It's because of progaurd.

For example, if you serialize an object to JSON and save it to disk in version N of your app without the proper keep rules, the saved data might look like this: {“a”: “Sue”, “b”: 28}. Because ProGuard renamed your fields to a and b, everything will seem to work, data will be saved and loaded correctly.

However, when you build your app again and release version N+1 of your app, ProGuard might decide to rename your fields to something different, such as c and d. As a result, data saved previously will fail to load.

```
-keep class <packagename.models>.** {
  *;
}
```

and @Keep annotation on my DATA classes, app started working.

Thanks wkalicinski for his article on medium about progaurd.